# extract numbers from string in bash script

Tags: string, bash, numbers

My code is like this:

- `xinput list | grep TouchPad`

then I get:

- ⎜   ↳ `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer 
  (2)]`

I save this output to a string variable in this way:

- `touchpad=$(xinput list | grep TouchPad)`

So, my question is, how can I save the ID number 14 as into a number variable in the bash script? I need to use that number to turn off the TouchPad by this:

- `xinput set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 0`

I need to run the code automatically, so the number 14 in the above code should come from the previous code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Bash Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
var='SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad id=14 [slave pointer (2)]'
num="${var/*TouchPad id=/}" # replaces ...TouchPad id= with empty string
num="${num/ */}"            # replaces space... with empty string
echo "$num"
```

Or

```
num="${var#*TouchPad id=}" # deletes ...TouchPad id= from var and assigns the remaining to num
num="${num%% *}"           # deletes space... from num
```

Or using grep with Perl regex:

```
echo "$var" |grep -oP "(?<=TouchPad id=)\d+"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num=$(echo " SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad id=14 [slave pointer (2)]" | grep -o '\d\d')
echo $num
```

**OUTPUT**

```
14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
touchpad='SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad id=14 [slave pointer (2)]'
sed -r 's~.*TouchPad id=([0-9]+).*~\1~' <<< "$touchpad"
14
```

Answer (score 0):

In your bash script:

```
regex="id=([0-9]+)"
[[ $touchpad =~ $regex ]]
id=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
if [ -z $id ]; then
   echo "Couldn't parse id for $touchpad"
else
    xinput set-prop $id "Device Enabled" 0
fi
```